# can't check a member variable when using future wait_for, but if I sleep in thread, it works

Tags: c++

I am using `std::future` and `wait_for()` to set a timeout, waiting for a zookeeper connection done.
I keep checking `connected_` in a while loop of thread. if I don't sleep in the loop, `wait_for()` always returns timeout, but I'm sure that `connected_` has been set.
If I sleep a few milliseconds in the while loop, it works well. Time of `connection_timeout_` is long enough. So what's wrong with my code?

```cpp
std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [this]{
      while(true){
        usleep(1000);//if delete this line, I get timeout always
        if(connected_){
          return 0;
        }
      }
    });
    auto status = fut.wait_for(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>{connection_timeout_});

    if(status == std::future_status::deferred){
      LOGGER_ERROR(Log::GetLog(), "wait for zk connection: deferred");
      return -1;
    }else if(status == std::future_status::timeout){
      LOGGER_ERROR(Log::GetLog(), "wait for zk connection: timeout");
      return -1;
    }else{// status == std::future_status::ready
      LOGGER_INFO(Log::GetLog(), "wait for zk connection: connected");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems ok to me. It seems the culprit may be that `connected_` was not set before timeout all the time. here's a test code:

```
std::atomic<bool> connected_ = false;
std::chrono::milliseconds connection_timeout_ = std::chrono::milliseconds(100);

struct foo {

    std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [this] {
        while (true) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000));
            if (connected_) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
};


int main()
{
    foo f;
    std::thread([]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50)); // connected_ set set after:  500 = timeout , 50 = connected
        connected_ = true;
    }).detach();

    auto status = f.fut.wait_for(std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>(connection_timeout_));


    if (status == std::future_status::deferred) {
        std::cout<<  "wait for zk connection: deferred\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
        std::cout << "wait for zk connection: timeout\n";
        return -1;
    }
    else if ( status == std::future_status::ready) {
        std::cout << "wait for zk connection: connected\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you!  it works after I change ```bool connected_``` to ```std::atomic<bool> connected_```. But I don't understand why ...

Comment: std::atomic guarantees not to cause data races and helps to synchronize memory accesses across threads.

Comment: it seems one thread write ```connected_```, and another thread keep reading ```connected_``` in a loop, but never get the new value. ```atomic``` makes the new value can be seen. if the new value write to the memory after timeout without ```atomic```? then we fix the order?

Comment: Should be a data race condition that is causing the behavior. In multi-threaded environment, the shared resources need to be protected during read/write using mutex, std::atomic is just another option.